# ¿Por qué no puedo crear mi archivo .log en Log4j y me manda el mensaje WARN File option not set for appender [A1]?

Tags: java, neo4j

Estoy creando un projecto con Netbeans y Java, y mi archivo log me permite ver los errores de éste, cree mis loggers en mis clases y configure mi log4j de la siguiente forma:

```
#log4j.rootCategory=A1
#log4j.rootCategory=A1

#LOGGER CONFIG
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1


log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appedner.logfile.File = traza.log
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.file.File=D:\ruta\a\mi\src\traza.log
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-13d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}%-4p[%t](%F:%L)-%m %n
#log4j.appender.A1.Target=D:\ruta\a\mi\src\traza.log
```

A pesar de eso, sigue sin aparecer el la carpeta especificada mi archivo .log y me manda el siguiente mensaje de error.

> log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [A1].
>
> log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
>
> log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [A1].

¿Por qué pasa esto?, ¿Debo modificar mis target o qué está mal en la configuración que no me permite continuar?

Answer (score 3):

Lo unico que veo mal es un error en `log4j.appedner.logfile.File = traza.log`
esta usando `appedner` cuando deberia ser `appender`

ademas de eso esta llamando una segunda variable en ves utilizar el **A1**

```
log4j.appender.A1.file.File=D:\Apps\MDinero\SPT_DRIVER_PFI\src\traza.log
```

deberia ser

```
log4j.appender.A1.File=D:\Apps\MDinero\SPT_DRIVER_PFI\src\traza.log
```

[aqui](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) explican mejor como configurar el propertie